# Remember Old Random Numbers? Java

Tags: java, random, numbers, generator

In order to prevent duplicates in my random number generator, I want to make an if statement that tests if my random number (x) is the same as any other previous values of x.  If it is, then it returns and restarts the loop.

How do I have my code remember all of the previous values of `x`?

Pseudocode:

```
if (x == previous value of x) {
   return;
}
```

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: Totally wrongheaded.  If you're concerned about your random number generator, run the die hard tests to find the period of repetition.

Comment: What would you recommend for testing repeating values?

Comment: @Win If it for fun, I posted my answer

Comment: Use a random number generator with a sufficiently long period before repetition occurs.

Comment: @duffymo: Die hard tests aren't relevant to this question.  Good random number generators _will_ produce duplicate values without cycling, and some of the best ones have cycles so long that you couldn't possibly determine them by explicit enumeration testing. If you generate 2 digit decimal numbers from a 32 bit generator, there will be duplicates.  If you generate `int`s using Java's built-in generator, which is a 48 bit LCG, there will be duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, pjs.  I stand by my original thought: keeping a list and checking for dupes will kill CPU and memory.  I'd recommend rethinking.

Comment: @duffymo Agreed, for reasonable sized lists the shuffle solution is the best choice. For larger lists, duplicates start becoming an issue at around sqrt(list.length).

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**: For example, you can make a list that contains 8 numbers and after that shuffle the list in order to be randomized what you want.

Code:

```
   Integer[] array = new Integer[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        array[i] = i+1;
    }
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(list.get(i) + " ");
    }
```

Output:

> 88 25 24 15 92 87 14 100 68 98 91 32 28 22 74 37 10 90 44 77 94 52 34
>   86 72 99 46 71 36 26 69 55 82 79 19 78 60 49 70 85 33 66 45 57 61 9 51
>   76 3 42 16 29 84 93 58 2 53 97 6 17 13 43 12 56 35 96 83 40 38 59 50 5
>   41 65 11 23 73 4 47 89 1 81 21 80 63 48 20 27 64 54 18 75 30 62 39 31
>   7 8 67 9

Comment: Is there a way to make a list, similarly to an array, contain values 1 through 100 rather than randomly typing out each one?

Comment: Rather than building an array and then converting it to a `List`, just start with `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: @pjs thank you for reminding me :) but the op just wanted 100 elements so I thought array is the right data structure :)

Comment: @Win what happened? did u solve ur issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use a array to record the previous value of `x`..... and check if the currently value inside that array..

Comment: Performance will get worse and worse as you add values.  Sounds like a great way to kill both performance and memory.

Comment: I think we can add some optimize;

    MAX = 1000;
    boolean array[1000] = {False};
    int x = generate_a_random_number (MAX);
    if (array[x] == False){
        array[x]=Ture;
        print x;
    }

Comment: What's the point of checking 1000?  Still makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list to record the previous values of x. List are better than arrays for this purpose, because you don't need to resize them if you want to generate more random numbers.

```
List<int> randomNumberList = new ArrayList<int>();
randomNumberList.add(randomNumberThatYouGenerated);
```

then just use an if:

```
if (randomNumberList.contains(randomNumberThatYouGenerated)) {
    //code
}
```